# Page-break-inside:avoid not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, printing, page-break-inside

I have a print stylesheet for my (Wordpress) site, and I want images to print on a single page rather than being split across pages. In some cases, even lines of text are being split across pages. I've included `img {page-break: avoid;)` in my print stylesheet, but no luck. I've found some previous answers but they're kind of old.

Is there a reliable way to print a moderately-sized image on a single page rather than splitting it across pages? Why are lines of text breaking across pages?

[image: picture broken across two pages]

[image: lines breaking across pages]

Site: http://74.220.217.211/housing-developments/grafton-townhomes/

Related posts:

- **[Print styles: How to ensure image doesn't span a page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649169/print-styles-how-to-ensure-image-doesnt-span-a-page-break)**
- [What are most useful media="print" specfic ,cross browser compatible css properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226939/what-are-most-useful-media-print-specfic-cross-browser-compatible-css-propert)
- [What is the correct way to do the CSS to avoid page breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331383/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-the-css-to-avoid-page-breaks)
- [page-break-inside doesn't work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706504/page-break-inside-doesnt-work-in-chrome)
- [Work around for page-break-inside:avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432044/work-around-for-page-break-insideavoid)

Comment: try adding `position: relative` to the parent

Comment: @riskbreaker, thanks! I'm not sure which parent to add that to though.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 25):

It could be that the parent element of the img element has style:

```
display: flex
```

Then the break-inside doesn’t work.

For example if you change parent element display style to:

```
display: block
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Oh! What a peculiar gotcha! If you have a reference link, it would be helpful.

Comment: Never thought about this!! Also check this thread for alternative solution for display:flex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408033/how-to-get-page-break-inside-avoid-to-work-nicely-with-flex-wrap-wrap Thanks

Comment: Just fyi - `display:flex` can cause issues but not guaranteed to be a problem. Also, `display:grid` also can cause issues

Answer (score 21):

Different browsers have weird limitations for `page-break-inside: avoid`. Following limitations have been suggested in different articles:

- If the document tree has the parent or grandparent with `display:flex` or `display:grid`, avoiding page-breaks will not work.
- If the parent element has `display:inline-block`, `avoid` doesn't work.
- In some cases, parent element needs `position:relative` for the value `avoid` to work in children. (Exact rules unknown.)
- In some cases, both the parent element and the element that needs to avoid breaking needs `position:relative` for the value `avoid` to work. (Exact rules unknown.)
- The parent element MUST NOT have `display: inline-block`.
- The element MUST NOT have `display:table-cell`.

In short, `@media print` styles should probably avoid using `float`, `flex`, `grid`, `position:absolute` and `position:sticky` if you need to use `page-break-inside: avoid`. For best compatibility with different browsers, try to define whole tree from root to parent with `display:block` and the element that shouldn't break with `display:inline-block` in addition to `page-break-inside: avoid`.

None of the above exceptions are part of any specs so these are just bugs or limitations in browser implementations.

Also note that even though latest specs prefer `break-inside: avoid` instead of `page-break-inside: avoid` the real world browser supports is still pretty bad. I would recommend declaring both:

```
.nobreak
{
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid
}
```

Comment: See also: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/02/css-fragmentation/

Comment: See also: my hack for keeping headers on the same page with the following content https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268825/334451

Comment: Another limitation for your list is: When parent /and/ child declare "page-break-inside: avoid" only the child is kept on one page; the parent will undergo a break.

Comment: If parent, however, has `overflow: auto` additionally to `page-break-inside: avoid`, parent has sane break avoidance (independend of (grand)child) but margin-collapsing doesn't work any more (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755272/12227050).

Comment: @jifb: which browser and which version number you had?

Comment: Browser is: wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt). This internally has Qt4 Webkit Engine (ten years old) see https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html (But still useful and there are still people contributing - see: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/pull/5167)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried to use `wkhtmltopdf` but it had so much problems with modern web pages that we're nowadays using Electron based version. See e.g. https://github.com/fraserxu/electron-pdf

Comment: "Following limitations have been suggested in different articles ..." proceeds to not link to a single article ...

Comment: The spec do specifies some of the limitations mentioned, for example the inline block exception for parents. See *Applies to* in https://drafts.csswg.org/css-break-3/#propdef-break-inside

Comment: Yes, that lists some exceptions but real world user agents have *a lot more* exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may come from the `position` property of elements. The element you don't want to break at page end and its parent should be declared as:

```
position: relative;
```

The rest of code styles is right and should looks like

```
@media print {
    img {
        page-break-before: auto;
        page-break-after: auto; 
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.site-container, .site-inner (heck body tag possibly) {position:relative;}

p {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    position: relative; 
}
```

Check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/petersphilo/QCvA5/5/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=QCvA5)

Add that in your print media

I just review this in Chrome and it looks fine minus the image which also needs this:

```
img {
    page-break-before: auto;
    page-break-after: auto; 
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    display: block;
}
```

Lastly Wordpress has this but in reality not sure if it helps...

```
 <!--nextpage-->
```

Comment: Tried it, but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you putting this in your WP files?

Comment: might want to check that theme - if you add at least the `img` tag on the print media and still get no results then might be more to the theme to implement

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    page-break-before: auto;
    page-break-after: auto; 
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    display: block;
}
```

this will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a four year old question with three other answers it is useful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses and to acknowledge if the passage of time has made new answers possible. In this case your answer is very similar to an existing answer, but is code only, lacking explanation, and it doesn't have details that the other answer has like the use of `@media print {`

Answer (score 0):

Use **@media print** and set a suitable **height** for the **page body** element or set **small size** for the **image**

**For example:**

```
@media print{
body{
height: 800px;
}
}
```