# CSS Margin of internal div extending past surrounding div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b6bpzsg7/

It comprises 3 portfolio items which are divs with class porthole which just have left and right padding for offset to neighbour.

```
<div class="col-md-4 porthole">
    <div class="portbox text-center">
         <div class="portplace">
            <div>Coming soon</div>
          </div>
          <header>Second</header>
     </div>
</div>
```

The inner div has a class of portbox which I can see in chrome developer does not expand vertically to take up all of the porthole surrounding it. portbox has no padding, border or margin

[image]

Within the portbox there is a placeholder div with class portplace that has a margin of 15px all around and padding top and bottom of 30px. In chrome developer I see that the top margin extends outside of the enclosing portbox to the top margin of the outside porthole.

[image]

Can someone enlighten me?

**EDIT**

```
   .portrow {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background-color: #888;
    }

    .porthole {
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
        overflow: auto;
    }   

    .portbox {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    }

    .portplace {
        margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
        background-color: lightgray;
        color: darkslategrey;
    }
```

Comment: Post your CSS. I'm guessing you probably don't mean to be using margin there, and it's pushing up on your container. If you look in the first screenshot, notice how the blue goes higher than the content - that's because of this 15px margin you have on the inner div. My suggestion would be don't use margin there.

Comment: It in the fiddle but I'll edit for convenience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` to your parent `div`:

https://jsfiddle.net/pavy/b6bpzsg7/2/

```
.portbox {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: auto; // you need this
}
```

Read up on collapsing margins:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: Can you explain why it happens?

Comment: You need to read up on collapsing margins to understand why it happens. This is how margins behave. Alternatively, use padding instead. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow="hidden" to the portbox to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you explain why it happens?

Comment: There is a good explanation on Mozilla under Parent and first/last child -- 
"If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent." Here's the full article on Mastering Margins:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: You can think about it this way...a block-level element has a (0,0) point which is found to the top and left of the padding, not the margin of that element.  For example, if you wanted to put a background image in or absolutely position a child object it seeks the (0,0) point from the padding if there is any.  When overflow is static (default) it simply takes the (0,0) point of its first child and matches it to its own (0,0) point.  Does that make sense?

Comment: BTW, I personally like overflow: hidden over overflow: auto since I'm not interested in scrolling bars which would appear if you had a fixed-dimension container and content that continues past the container's bottom or right edge.

Comment: It does make sense. (As far as css can make sense :) ). It makes css a quite difficult road for someone coming from classical UI design. Nothing works straight off. Compared to something like screen design for android or iOS which almost always works as expected and leaves more time and nerves for fine tuning.